# iPhone detect touch when screen is locked

Tags: iphone, lockscreen

I know that apple knows when you touch the locked screen (iPod shortcut, call), but can I know somehow when user touches it.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, your window (which would accept the touch) is not active when the screen is locked.